# Should I strive for a deeper understanding of everything, or just a surface level understanding for tests

Tags: soft-question, education, advice

I currently find myself in a weird situation, where I know a lot about surface level math (e.g. basic math, quadratics, algebra), and not a lot about the deeper level, and I am conflicted as to if I should continue forward to higher level math (e.g. complex numbers, logs, calculus, and such), or if I should repeat lower level math, this time, striving for deeper understanding. What should I do?

Comment: I think we do not know enough about you to answer.  Try asking one of your past instructors.  Or one of the instructors of a higer-level course you are considering.

Comment: This is a very difficult situation, and it really depends where you are at currently. If you feel like you understood almost nothing with your lower level math classes, then repeat; it will hurt you more if you continue. If you feel like you understood a good portion (or at least enough to do tests), then continue; your understanding will grow as you continue. You might just have to work harder than others in your class in order to keep up.